# Issue using my Gmail account to send email in Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, gmail

I am trying to use my Gmail account to send emails in a Laravel 9 project. I have a custom domain and have setup a custom gmail workspace account. Using that account, I generated an app password, and used that to send emails on my local serve, and it works. Here are the settings in the .env for the mail server:

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=example@silkweb.ca
MAIL_PASSWORD="***********"      
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=example@silkweb.ca
MAIL_REPLYTO_ADDRESS=xyz@gmail.com 
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

I am able to send emails using the above configuration on the local server on my Mac. However, when I use exactly same settings on the production server (my domain silkweb.ca), I get an error message:

```
Symfony\Component\Mailer\Exception\TransportException     PHP 8.0.26. 9.24.0
Expected response code "250/251/252" but got code "550", with message "550 5.7.1 Relaying denied".
```

Here are the details about the request sent by PHP

```
curl "https://silkweb.ca/password/email" \
 -X POST \
 -H 'cookie: XSRF-  
TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IlNKbExabVZGZFdVMFRDL3ZBdFZnWUE9......' \
 -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' \
 -H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br' \
 -H 'referer: https://silkweb.ca/password/reset' \
 -H 'sec-fetch-dest: document' \
 -H 'sec-fetch-user: ?1' \
 -H 'sec-fetch-mode: navigate' \
 -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' \
 -H 'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,.....\
 -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' \
 -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
 -H 'origin: https://silkweb.ca' \
 -H 'upgrade-insecure-requests: 1' \
 -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"' \
 -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
 -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Not?A_Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="108", "Google Chrome";v="108"' \
 -H 'cache-control: max-age=0' \
 -H 'content-length: 74' \
 -H 'connection: keep-alive' \
 -H 'host: silkweb.ca' \
 -F '_token=WQnq9y7JklvDiU5hqORymYvorevDOgOReoPPB2uc' -F 'email=rktaxali@gmail.com'
```

Any suggestion, how to fix this issue?

Comment: Relaying denied is a message you'd expect when you're not properly authenticated, which would possibly point to a difference between your dev .env and your production .env.

Comment: @AlexHowansky, I copied MAIL settings from my dev .env to the production .env. I have once again checked -- they have the same settings.

Comment: have you tried running `php artisan config:cache`  on your production server?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what was the issue, but smtp.gmail.com has started working. I cleared cache and congig cache (php artisan cache:clear  and php artisan congig:clear). I also changed the encryption to tls and port to 587. I also removed quotes (") from the passwrod. Then, first I used my personal gmail account with smtp.gmail.com and it worked. Later I tried my custom gmail account (from my domain silkweb.ca) and that I also worked. The following settings are working for me:

```
# Google SMTP configuration
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=example@silkweb.ca
MAIL_PASSWORD=**********
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=example@silkweb.ca
```

When I was searching for answers for my issue on the net, I came across an article Google: https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en
As per this article, the recommended method to send emails from a gmail account is smtp-relay.gmail.com.

Comment: Exactly, after configuring SMTP configuration it's highly recommended to clear your application cached configuration!
just `php artisan optimize:clear` will handle the rest! but make sure that the port, username, and password are correct!